# My MyEtherWallet address is different than the first address it gave me

Tags: addresses, private-key, myetherwallet

I invest to TheDAO this week and I don't see my transaction.

My address is: 0x72eb41AE7f943445Da9932662d31A06D56A3cfAa

But when I look my wallet whith my private key I see an other: 0x110C7C6a224122F72619b18A1b3f712957E4EbF1

I dont understand why ist changing ... Where is my coins ?

Comment: What version of your private key did you save?

Comment: have you tried to search for these accounts on a blockchain explorer ? Both seems to be valid bu no ether and no transactions. So I doubt that you used these accounts for anything.

Comment: I've got the same question. My coins are there, but the address is completely different. I can sign in also. I never did any typing, I copied and pasted onto a USB to save the address. I'm a little leery about sending to the new address now that it has changed.

Answer (score 1):

When typing your unencrypted private key by hand, you need to be ultra careful that you type in correctly. Mistyping a single number or letter will access a different wallet, and make it appear that your address has changed.

Alternatively you could use the QR code on the paper wallet, or save the QR code when you first generate the wallet, in order to decrease the likelihood of this happening.

A lot of times when you first mistyped it and see a different wallet / no balance your adrenaline starts rushing and you start freaking out which only makes things worse. Ive gotten emails like, "everytime I try to access my wallet it spits out a brand new address". Take a deep breath. Retype it, carefully. It'll be okay.